# Image cannot been displayed with strange name

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload

I have a code that let my users to upload images and it works fine till I discoverd when the image file name is something like this  "Suzuki_Swift_1.2_Comfort_(FZ_NZ)_â€“_Frontansicht,_26._MÃ¤rz_2011,_DÃ¼sseldorf.jpg "

When I upload this image, Im getting broken imgage icon.
And when I upload the same image with the name "Suzuki_Swift_1.2_Comfort" it works fine.

Here is my html and php code for upload the image into a path in my database!

Why is this happening and how can I fix it,?

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="foto"   onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

PHP:

```
 <?php


 if (isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($errors) === true )
{
    $name=basename($_FILES['foto']['name']);
    $t_name=$_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
    $dir='upload';
  if ($_FILES['foto']['size'] >= 2097152) {
  $errors[] = '- Big file';
  } else {  
    if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))
        {
    $path=$dir."/".$name;


        }
}
  }
?>
```

Img tag:

```
<?php    $photo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adver ORDER BY car_id DESC LIMIT");
while($get_photo=mysql_fetch_array($photo)){ ?>
 <a href="<?php echo 'car-details.php?merk='.$get_photo['merk'] .'&car_id='  .$get_photo['car_id'] .'&titel=' .$get_photo['titel'] ;?>">        


<img src="<?php  echo   $get_photo['path']; ?>" style="border:1px solid #021a40;" alt=" <?  php  echo $get_photo['merk'] ;?>" />
```

Comment: When you try and display, what is the `src` of the `img` tag?

Comment: See my code: I have just edit it there.

Comment: No, when you view source in the browser.

Comment: oh sorry, This is why i get:
img src="upload/Suzuki_Swift_1.2_Comfort_(FZ_NZ)_–_Frontansicht,_26._März_2011,_Düsseldorf.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename the image to a random string this will stop illegal characters getting through and safe guard against two users uploading different images with the same name.